# Can I make the srollbars in macOS wider?

Tags: big-sur, macos

The default scroll bar width in macOS is annoyingly narrow. E.g. when in iMovie or Photoshop, when I want to scroll through the video timeline, respectively image I cannot drag to left or right, but only use the almost inaccessible scroll bars.
And these are so narrow, that when I approach the horizontal scroll bar at the bottom, the Dock pops up and I start another app. This annoyance is already since Snow Leopard 10.6, now I use Big Sur 10.16 and it is still not fixed. (By the way, Linux and Windows have the same issues).
I have made the dock auto-hide to get more 'screen real estate'. But why is the scroll bar so narrow ?

Is there a trick to make them wider ?

Or another trick: enable dragging, like on a touch screen, when scrolling horizontally.

Comment: Shift/scroll will scroll horizontally.

Comment: That worked. But initially not, because I had Mos installed, which allows natural scrolling on trackpad, and 'legacy' (which is reverse) mouse scrolling with mouse, which cannot be combined natively in macOS. And in that app, horizontal scroll was disabled and now I checked it by using the shift key, so now it does work, even with Mos enabled.